# having a problem making a foreign key from a table to another in laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I'm doing a project in Laravel and I came across this problem whenever I try to migrate the project :

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `invoices`.`invoice_attachments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `invoice_attach
ments` add constraint `invoice_attachments_invoice_id_foreign` foreign key (`invoice_id`) references `invoices` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at E:\Laravel\invoices\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );


  1   E:\Laravel\invoices\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:544
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `invoices`.`invoice_attachments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

  2   E:\Laravel\invoices\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:544
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

my goal is to make a table called invoice_attachments which have an invoice_id that connects it to invoices table.
here is the code for the invoices table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('invoices')) {
            Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {

                $table->id();
                $table->string('invoice_number', 50);
                $table->date('invoice_Date')->nullable();
                $table->date('Due_date')->nullable();
                $table->string('product', 50);
                $table->bigInteger('section_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('section_id')->references('id')->on('sections')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->decimal('Amount_collection', 8, 2)->nullable();;
                $table->decimal('Amount_Commission', 8, 2);
                $table->decimal('Discount', 8, 2);
                $table->decimal('Value_VAT', 8, 2);
                $table->string('Rate_VAT', 999);
                $table->decimal('Total', 8, 2);
                $table->string('Status', 50);
                $table->integer('Value_Status');
                $table->text('note')->nullable();
                $table->date('Payment_Date')->nullable();
                $table->softDeletes();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('invoices');
    }
};
```

here is the code for the invoice_attachments table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('invoice_attachments')) {
            Schema::create('invoice_attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('file_name', 999);
                $table->string('invoice_number', 50);
                $table->string('Created_by', 999);
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('invoice_id')->unsigned();
                //$table->foreign('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('sections')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('invoice_attachments');
    }
};
```

and here's the order of migration files in the project:
[image]

I've tried changing the type of id in invoices to bigIncrement and didn't work
**problem update**
the solutions worked just fine for invoice_attachment but i'm having the same problem on invoice details table
note that I'm using the same code here's my code in invoice details:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('invoice_details')) {

            Schema::create('invoice_details', function (Blueprint $table) {

                $table->id();
                $table->string('invoice_number', 50);
                $table->foreignId('invoice_id')->references('id')->on('invoices')->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
                $table->string('product', 50);
                $table->string('Section', 999);
                $table->string('Status', 50);
                $table->integer('Value_Status');
                $table->date('Payment_Date')->nullable();
                $table->text('note')->nullable();
                $table->string('user', 300);
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('invoice_details');
    }
};
```

Comment: You often see this when the datatypes for `id` and `{foreign}_id} differ, or the migrations are in the wrong order. Checking your code: Order is fine (`invoices` comes before `invoice_attachments`), `$table->id();` in `invoices` table creates a `UNSIGNED BIGINT` `id`,  `$table->unsignedBigInteger('invoice_id')->unsigned();` should do the same (the `->unsigned()` at the end is redundant though). That _should_ work. If you have models, you can try the `$table->foreignIdFor(Invoice::class)->constrained();` method maybe? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignIdFor

Comment: Your code looks fine it matches the correct datatypes, but inspect you database to check invoices.id is unsigned big integer and the same for invoice attachmes invoice id.

Answer (score 1):

On your invoices table you are creating the ID column using this :

```
$table->id();
```

which will (from Laravel 8 upwards, I believe) create a column with a BIGINT of length 20, unsigned, not nullable, and primary key.

The easiest way of creating a column on another table that references that as a foreign key is to do the following in your 'invoice_attachments' migration :

```
$table->foreignId('invoice_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
```

This will automatically create the column and the foreign key - it will look for the column 'id' on the table 'invoices' - should either of those not be correct then you can specify using :

```
$table->foreignId('invoice_id')->references('column')->on('table')->constrained()->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();
```

That said, though, your code works for me on Laravel 9. It may be that you're using an earlier version where (from memory) the $table->id() created a 12 digit integer, not a 20 digit integer, and therefore using 'unsignedBigInteger' fails.

I would amend your invoices migration to specifically create the ID as a 20 digit biginter column and re-run.

Comment: I'm using laravel 9 and for the invoice_attachment table your solution workked for me but now i'm having a new problem on invoice_details the same problem as before but your solution didn't work on it
i'm gonna edit the question with the new problem details